# Purpose of Row sampling with replacement and feature sampling in Random Forest?

Tags: python, data-science, random-forest

In random forest we actually use bootstrap aggregation,actually we are following two steps like Row sampling with replacement and feature sampling for creating bootstrap sample,Actually my questions are

1)what is actual purpose of this row sampling and feature sampling?

2)In row sampling with replacement same rows can be repeated in the bootstrap sample right(correct me if i am wrong),if same rows are appearing twice how will it impact our final prediction is there any need of that replacement / Is that row sampling with replacement necessary?

3)Say if a dataset consists of 7 features, In feature sampling we actually select some of the columns
right if we select 4 columns only from our dataset will it affect our result?

please correct if i am wrong and help me by answering the correct method of bootstrap sampling in random Forest

[image]Is this bootstrap sample  created corrrect?(First data is our actual data other two are bootstrap samplees

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap Aggregating, a.k.a. Bagging

**Row sampling**

Bagging generally selects random samples/rows repeatedly with replacement and fits trees to these. This is a type of "model averaging", which makes the overall random forest model less likely to overfit on the training set, since the various trees are trained on different parts of the training set. This in turn reduces the variance, without increasing the bias [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating)].

**Column sampling**

As stated above, we *generally* only do this on the rows. But bagging can also be used on the columns, mostly for the same reasons as mentioned above. However, if you have a very "wide" dataset with lots of different features, doing bagging on the columns can help handle the *curse of dimensionality*

The idea for both techniques is that, even though one tree by itself would be highly sensitive to noise, the average of many trees is not.

**Why not random sampling *without* replacement?**

Good question. The easy answer is that, by definition, [bootstrapping is any test or metric that uses random sampling with replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). However, as this [paper](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/wxs/Learning-papers/paper-bag.pdf) points out, the results *with* and *without* replacement is almost similar, given that the dataset is sufficiently large.

Comment: hey i have a follow up question, must the no of features chosen in feature sampling for different datasets for trees in the forest be the same? Or can we have one tree with 3 features? And another with 2?

Comment: also should i add this as another question or would adding this q here in the comment suffice?

Comment: @jeremy sorry for the late reply actually number of features selected must be same for different data sets

Comment: @ViggoTW wouldn't duplicate rows in each tree's training set (from sampling with replacement) hurt the robustness of each tree?